# Is there an issue with transparent png using WhitespaceTrimmer plugin

Tags: imageresizer

When I try to trim an image that has a transparent background using the WhitespaceTrimmer plugin i end up with a 3x3 image with nothing in it.

However when I save my source image in paint and the transparent background becomes a solid white background the WhitespaceTrimmer works great.

Am I doing anything wrong which would make the trimmer not function on my original image or is this some sort of bug or unsupported feature?

Original source:

[image: Original Source]

Output of original source (there is a 3x3 image there somewhere):

[image: Output Of Original Source]

Original image saved with a white background (using MS Paint):

[image: Source Saved With White Background]

Output of white background image:

[image: Output Of White Background Image]

Test Code used to output image through asp.net

```
    Response.Clear()

    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=testSigOutput.png")
    Response.ContentType = diFunctions.getContentType("png")

    ImageBuilder.Current.Build("C:\Solutions\TestImages\testSig.png", Response.OutputStream, New ResizeSettings("trim.threshold=80&trim.percentpadding=0.5"))
    Response.End()
```

**Edit:** I did some additional testing, I have come to the conclusion that when it converts the image to grayscale it is treating transparent pixels as black.

Regardless of what color I set the transparent background pixels to it will not work.

However if I change the pen color or make the background slightly visible (0.01 alpha) it works fine.

So the answer is I have a work around but is this working as intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WhitespaceTrimmer [converts images to grayscale so that an energy filter can be applied](https://github.com/imazen/resizer/blob/master/Plugins/WhitespaceTrimmer/BoundingBoxFinder.cs#L60). It's likely that your image turns into a black square when converted to grayscale. To test this, try making the figure in your image a different color (but still against a transparent background).

Another possibility is that the transparent pixels in the image are of the same color, and thus the outline only exists in the alpha channel - which is not multiplied against the other channels.

Comment: I did some additional testing, I have come to the conclusion that when it converts the image to grayscale it is treating transparent pixels as black. Regardless of what color I set the transparent background pixels to it will not work.  However if I change the pen color or make the background slightly visible (0.01 alpha) it works fine.  So the answer is I have a work around but is this working as intended?

Comment: It's difficult to determine a good solution for dealing with the alpha channel. Which matte color do we choose - and render broken? Typically this plugin is used with photographs; already-transparent images don't have much to lose in terms of file size.

Comment: I guess my only remaining comment would be that I would think it should recognize the transparent pixels as their original color, rather than converting them to black. Then you wouldn't need to do the seemingly strange slightly visible alpha on the background pixels to make it work.  Anyways, thanks for the assistance.

Comment: *Most* PNG converters actually drop the RGB channels when Alpha is at zero. WhitespaceTrimmer doesn't 'convert' anything to black - that's actually the color it sees as present. Can your photo editor save/reopen a PNG with Alpha=0 pixels and preserve the original color?